# How to globally add a Vue tooltip component to all elements which have a traditional tooltip attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am converting an application from Handlbars + Semantic UI to Vue3 + [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#tooltips) as the front-end control library, and have come across one difference which seems tricky to port.

In my original app I have widespread use of `data-tooltip` attributes, which Semantic UI automatically upgrades to prettier popover/tooltips - with no extra markup required.

Furthermore some of these tooltips would have become annoying for regular/pro users, so I added a feature to "disable tooltips" and added a `data-app-tooltip` attribute which wrapped the Semantic UI data-tooltip feature with respect to the per-user setting. It was simple: a JQuery function ran on page-load which rewrote the app-specific tooltip attributes to standard ones if the user had not turned them off.

I can see the [Vuetify tooltip component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#tooltips) is a different thing - you need a bunch of markup associated with a triggering component, either wrapping it or you can target the activator.

What I'd like to do is keep all my `tooltip="xxxx"` attributes and replicate my one-off transform to add the required sibling/child/parent components to the Vue DOM.

Previously in Semantic UI i had this in the page-load template

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Disable tooltips on user config.
        if(confTooltips){
            // convert  placeholders to actual tooltips
            $("[data-app-tooltip]").each(function(i,el){
                var $el = $(el);
                $el.attr('data-tooltip', $el.attr('data-app-tooltip'));
            });
        }
    })
```

and an example UI which had an optional tooltip would be:

```html
    <a href="/app/mode/full"
       class="ui mini basic icon item"
       data-app-tooltip="Show the full navigation controls"
    >
        <i class="icon angle right"></i>
    </a>
```

So what I'd like now is a Vue global transform which would turn all elements on each page which have the `data-app-tooltip` attribute into something with a sibling component from
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/

So for example this item

```vue
    <span v-bind="props" data-app-tooltip="The number of items imported from this file">
       {{ item.count }} 
    </span>
```

should be automatically transformed to something like this:

```vue
    <v-tooltip text="The number of items imported from this file">
       <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <span v-bind="props">
                 {{ item.count }} 
           </span>
         </template>
    </v-tooltip>
```

Or whatever the simplest possible Vuetify tooltip can be (it all seems rather complex and the documentation is a bit lacking)

Perhaps there is a more general question here: how to transform Vue templates into another form before it is instantiated by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a directive for that.

Check https://primevue.org/tooltip/ for an example on how would it look like

```js
<InputText v-tooltip="'Enter your username'" type="text" placeholder="Right" />
<InputText v-tooltip.top="'Enter your username'" type="text" placeholder="Top" />
<InputText v-tooltip.bottom="'Enter your username'" type="text" placeholder="Bottom" />
<InputText v-tooltip.left="'Enter your username'" type="text" placeholder="Left" />
```

You may use code from https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9610#issuecomment-1613601337 or `useDirectiveComponent` from https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/17395/files for that

related: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9610 , https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/17395

Comment: I'm not using that front-end library, I'm using Vuetify. That one looks similar to how SemanticUI used to work.

Comment: @scipilot linked Vuetify PR and a solution in issue